# Running a Batch File from Task Scheduler With User credentials automatic fetch from directory

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-task, batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch file on Windows 7 from the Task Scheduler. I can run the batch file fine if I run it from the command prompt and by storing user credentials in Task schedular.

However, User's password changes per month so i need to find a way so that Task Scheduler can Automatically fetch user credentials from a directory to run Schedular.

Any help will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the user password, You will need to change the password on the task to get everything working again.

My suggestion: Create a service account to run the task and set the password to never expire.